# Embedding language and framework in an architecture diagram using architecture as code

Tags: python

I want to show that in my GPC function it has NodeJS and the language in that is Javascript, and have that cluster point to a GPC storage node.

I am using a library from [diagrams.mingrammer.com](https://diagrams.mingrammer.com)

```
from diagrams import Cluster, Diagram, Edge
from diagrams.gcp.compute import Functions
from diagrams.gcp.storage import GCS
from diagrams.gcp.storage import Storage
from diagrams.gcp.ml import SpeechToText
from diagrams.onprem.client import User, Users, Client
from diagrams.gcp.compute import Run
from diagrams.gcp.compute import ContainerOptimizedOS
from diagrams.gcp.ml import SpeechToText
from diagrams.programming.language import Python, Nodejs, Javascript
from diagrams.onprem.compute import Server

with Diagram("PII Project Backend", show=False):
    quarantineStorage = Storage("quarantine")
    textStorage = Storage("pre-processed")
    processedStorage = Storage("processed")
    determineTypeFunction = Functions("determine type")
    sendToDLPFunction = Functions("pull from storage")

    with Cluster("Authorized User"):
        User("auth user") >> Edge(color="blue", label="GET") >> quarantineStorage

    with Cluster("Do DLP"):
        with Cluster("Process Step 1"):
            with Cluster("Detect File Type Function"):
                determineTypeFunction >> Nodejs("Function") >> Javascript("Look at extension on correct flow.")
            quarantineStorage >> determineTypeFunction
            with Cluster("Process Step 2"):
                with Cluster("Audio"):
                determineTypeFunction >> SpeechToText("transcribe") >> textStorage
                with Cluster("Process Step 2 Image"):
                    determineTypeFunction >> textStorage
                with Cluster("Process Step 2 Text"):
                    determineTypeFunction >> textStorage
            with Cluster("DLP Step"):
                sendToDLPFunction >> Python("Controller to route")
            textStorage >> sendToDLPFunction >> Server("DLP Classify") >> Server("DLP Encrypt") >> processedStorage
```

This resulted in [image: Architecture diagram] and as you can see I want to have the 'pull from storage' node to have nodejs within it and javascript within that.